# View a method's implementation (method body) using Java Reflection

Tags: java

I can view the methods of a class using java reflection.

```
    Method[] methods = Person.class.getMethods();
    for(Method method : methods){
        System.out.println("method = " + method);
    }
```

the `person` class ,

```
class Person{
String name;
int age;

Person(String name,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
public int count(){
    int count = 10*20;
    return count;
} 
}
```

Using reflection the `count` method will view like,
`method = public int Person.count()` but not the implementation (method body).

is there anyway to view the full implementation details of a method using this kind of approach or with any other ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this using standard Java tools. The source method implementation is not accessible in runtime. You can however load this class file as a resource and pass it to some [Java decompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Java_decompilers), which will try its best to produce the original source code of the class. Or course it's not guaranteed that the result will be 100% exact and it will be even worse if your class is compiled without debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sourceforge project. It takes class file as input, decompiles it, provides the source file and is platform independent:
[Java Decompiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcompiler/)